# Path in %PATH% doesn't work

Tags: windows-8, path, python3.2

I set my `Path` environment variable to look like this:

```
E:\Programy\Python; ... all the rest
```

but after I have it all confirmed and call `env` in command line, `E:\Programy\Python` is not listed there. How is that?

Comment: What is `env` ? How did you set the environment variable ? Did you try `SET` / `PATH` to list it ?

Comment: @Ofiris It displays environmental variables like Path

Comment: @Louis, aint it in Unix ?

Comment: @Ofiris No, he tagged it as Windows 8.

Comment: @Louis, I tried to type `env` in a win 8 cmd and it doesnt work..

Comment: @Ofiris Oh, I'm sorry, you're right. I forgot I have CoreUtils installed.

Comment: Do you use a standard user?

Comment: I use Administrator account. And yes, it's Win8, `env` works here as supposed. To change `PATH` I used My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying the PATH you need to close the Command Prompt window and reopen it for the changes to take effect.

Comment: See [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) for details regarding how to properly modify the PATH environment variable via the UI or command line (using `set/setx`) in Windows 8.